# JQuery $.get containing single quote and PHP returns backslash for single quote

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm sending data from client(javascript and Jquery library in particular) to server(running in PHP). The information I send is as follow:

From Chrome Dev Tool -> Network

```
Request URL:http://host:8888/RoviImages.php?id=880&aid=334&albumTitle=The+Lion%27s+Roar&albumId=MW0002231494
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

Query String Parameters
id:880
aid:334
albumTitle:The Lion's Roar
albumId:MW0002231494
```

The client code is:

```
var data = {id: song_id, aid: aid, albumTitle: albumTitle, albumId: albumId};
$.get(request_url, data)
```

Checking the information before sending it I get the albumTitle as "**The Lion's Roar**"

When PHP received the information the first thing I do is to print it.

```
$albumTitle =    $_GET['albumTitle'];
error_log('Album Title = ' . $albumTitle);
```

This returns me with "**Album Title = The Lion\'s Roar**".

After processing the information I echo the response to javascript using **json_encode**. Javascript get the response and when it decodes it through **JSON.parse** the result is "**The Lion\'s Roar**".

So basically it gets in to the server but I get it back with changes. Why?

Comment: before using it on server side apply `stripslashes()` on it: `stripslashes($_GET['albumTitle'])` or if you have access disable magic quotes.

Comment: Could you put it as an answer?

Comment: Better disable magic quotes, see [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magic quotes setting is probably on. See https://www.php.net/security.magicquotes.

Add this at the top of your scrip to automatically strip all the slashes from the input:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $process = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);
    while (list($key, $val) = each($process)) {
        foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
            unset($process[$key][$k]);
            if (is_array($v)) {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = $v;
                $process[] = &$process[$key][stripslashes($k)];
            } else {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = stripslashes($v);
            }
        }
    }
    unset($process);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Disable magic quotes better, see [<kbd>HERE</kbd>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php), if you can't disable, you can remove using this:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    function stripslashes_gpc(&$value) {
        $value = stripslashes($value);
    }
    array_walk_recursive($_GET, 'stripslashes_gpc');
    array_walk_recursive($_POST, 'stripslashes_gpc');
    array_walk_recursive($_COOKIE, 'stripslashes_gpc');
    array_walk_recursive($_REQUEST, 'stripslashes_gpc');
}
```